# ModuleNotFound when running an app in Docker

Tags: python, docker, flask

I've got a Python3 Flask app, and I want to put it to container. I've added Flask to requirements.txt, and it works locally, but fails to find "flask" module when in container. What am I doing wrong?

requirements.txt:

```
aniso8601==7.0.0
certifi==2019.6.16
chardet==3.0.4
Click==7.0
Flask==1.1.1
Flask-RESTful==0.3.7
idna==2.8
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
pymongo==3.8.0
pytz==2019.1
requests==2.22.0
six==1.12.0
urllib3==1.25.3
Werkzeug==0.15.4
```

Minimal working `app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN apk add --no-cache \
        uwsgi-python3
COPY . .
ENV TESTING TRUE
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
CMD [ "uwsgi", "--socket", "0.0.0.0:3031", \
               "--uid", "uwsgi", \
               "--plugins", "python3", \
               "--protocol", "uwsgi", \
               "--wsgi", "app:app", \
               "-p", "4", \
               "--enable-threads"]
```

Error:

```
*** Operational MODE: preforking ***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./app.py", line 5, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, request, Response
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
```

[Example](https://gist.github.com/keddad/5b329a6c88e63ed84742cb47c6d4b11c) of app.py (too big to add to question)

Project structure:

```
├── app.py
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── LICENSE
├── logging_config.ini
├── nginx.conf
├── __pycache__
│   └── utils.cpython-37.pyc
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
├── testing_data
│   ├─- some jsons here
├── tests.py
└── utils.py
```

Comment: Would you mind adding a (very) shortened version of your `app.py` to your question as well?

Comment: You don't need pip3 if you declared python:3.7 in header. Try replacing pip3 with pip.
Otherwise please copy the file-structure of your project here. Do you have a .dockerignore file?

Comment: Added example of app, changing pip version makes no difference, and I don't have .dockerignore

Comment: You could have reduced the example app though to a minimum; that would have easily fit inside the question, and made it more reproducible.

Comment: @00 SO says that "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.", so looks like I can't (even if I remove everything but imports)

Comment: For what it's worth: I can reproduce your error. If I can create an identical image without the `CMD` section and run that (with `-ti` and `/bin/sh`, I am able to run `python3 app.py`. If I run `uwsgi --protocol uwsgi  --plugins python3 -s 0.0.0.0:3031 --wsgi app:app` instead, I'm back to the ModuleNotFoundErro again.

Answer (score 1):

Try use pip instead of pip3 and try copying requirements.txt to Docker root explicitly.
Also you need to create a workdir before using it.

Something like:

````
FROM python:3.7-alpine

COPY requirements.txt /
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY . app/

# not sure what this is doing
RUN apk add --no-cache \
        uwsgi-python3

# ENV TESTING TRUE

CMD [ "uwsgi", "--socket", "0.0.0.0:3031", \
               "--uid", "uwsgi", \
               "--plugins", "python3", \
               "--protocol", "uwsgi", \
               "--wsgi", "app:app", \
               "-p", "4", \
               "--enable-threads"]```
````

Answer (score 1):

*I've tried to replicate the error (no luck), but you might still find this useful. If you can edit your question with your `app.py` lines 1-5, I might be able to replicate it and update my answer.*

I've modified your Dockerfile with the inclusion of bash (line 5), so that you can get into the container and see what's going on -

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN apk add --no-cache \
        uwsgi-python3 \
        bash
COPY . .
ENV TESTING TRUE
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
CMD [ "uwsgi", "--socket", "0.0.0.0:3031", \
               "--uid", "uwsgi", \
               "--plugins", "python3", \
               "--protocol", "uwsgi", \
               "--wsgi", "app:app", \
               "-p", "4", \
               "--enable-threads"]
```

Rebuild the image

```
$ docker build . -t soflask
```

Run the container as a daemon

```
$ docker run -d --rm soflask
$ docker ps

CONTAINER ID ...
96f341e998d4 ...

$ docker exec -i -t 96f bash
$ python
>>> from flask import Flask
>>>
```

No errors... What does app.py lines 1 - 5 look like?

Comment: Added example to the question, but there is nothing special here

Comment: Still works fine... I'd try stopping the container (making sure I'm stopping the *right* container), re-build the image, and re-run the container. My only thought is that maybe you added to the Dockerfile and forgot to rebuild the image.

Comment: Well, I bashed into container, and _pip list_ tells me that I have all needed modules, so it appears to be some kind of bug. I'll just use another base container, as it worked normally with __alpine:3.10__. Not really an answer, but works OK as workaround

Comment: @biryulin04 if it does work with a specific version of Alpine, I would definitely note that as an answer, even if it doesn't explain the underlying cause. Other people searching for this problem may find your solution as well then.

Answer (score 0):

Well, running **alpine:3.10** helps, but because it currently comes with Python 3.6 (I need 3.7) I ended with such a Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.10
VOLUME /usr/src/app/public
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN apk add --no-cache python3 && \
    if [ ! -e /usr/bin/python ]; then ln -sf python3 /usr/bin/python ; fi && \
    python3 -m ensurepip && \
    rm -r /usr/lib/python*/ensurepip && \
    pip3 install --no-cache --upgrade pip setuptools wheel && \
    if [ ! -e /usr/bin/pip ]; then ln -s pip3 /usr/bin/pip ; fi
RUN apk add --no-cache \
        uwsgi-python3
COPY . .
RUN rm -rf public/*
ENV TESTING TRUE
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
CMD [ "uwsgi", "--socket", "0.0.0.0:3031", \
               "--uid", "uwsgi", \
               "--plugins", "python3", \
               "--protocol", "uwsgi", \
               "--wsgi", "app:app", \
               "-p", "4", \
               "--enable-threads"]
```

This *RUN apk add --no-cache python3...* magic was taken from [here](https://github.com/frol/docker-alpine-python3/blob/master/Dockerfile). Not sure how, but it just works.